# Video Transcoding/Conversion using Java

Tags: java, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I would like to convert a video from one format to another. Initially, I want to convert MP4 to AVI or any other more suitable video format.

Came across the ffmpeg library. Is is the best solution?

Came across Xubber and Jave for the same? Any experiences?

Answer (score 1):

I tried jffmpeg that is a direct java wrapper on ffmpeg, but didn't found much documentation over that so moved on.

I tried to use Xubber and succeded also but it requires lot of pre-configurartions like you have to install .exe file prior and set XUBBER_HOME vars etc.

I have found nice and easy to implement solution ie **JAVE** http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/index.php

Try this one.